# How to access button inside footer view under UITests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm struggling with accessing to button which is inside FooterView of TableView. This is the view:

[image]

I'm trying to tap on button inside red square.

```
    var loyaltyCardTable = app.tables["loyaltyCardTable"]

    loyaltyCardTable.otherElements.matching(identifier: "summaryLoyaltyCardFooter").element(boundBy: 0).buttons["informationButton"].tap()
```

When I'm trying to record the action I get error:
[image]

This is the output when I try stoped test and printed query:

```
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 0x1700b0140
  Output: {
    Application 0x17057b540: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}, label: 'DirectBistro'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Table
    Output: {
      Table 0x17457d400: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 554.0}}, identifier: 'loyaltyCardTable'
    }
    ↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"loyaltyCardTable" IN identifiers'
      Output: {
    Table 0x17457d400: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 554.0}}, identifier: 'loyaltyCardTable'
      }
      ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Other
       Output: {
        Other 0x17457d340: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, -262.0}, {375.0, 180.0}}
        Other 0x17457cd40: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 50.0}}
        Other 0x17457ce00: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0, 50.0}}
        Other 0x17457c500: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457c440: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457c380: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457c2c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x174576e00: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457c5c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}, identifier: 'summaryLoyaltyCardFooter'
        Other 0x17457c140: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 268.0}, {375.0, 50.0}}
        Other 0x17457c200: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 268.0}, {375.0, 50.0}}
        Other 0x17457b480: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 528.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457b3c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 528.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457b300: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 528.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457b180: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 528.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457a940: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 528.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}
        Other 0x17457b540: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 528.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}, identifier: 'summaryLoyaltyCardFooter'
      }
      ↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"summaryLoyaltyCardFooter" IN identifiers'
        Output: {
          Other 0x17457c5c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}, identifier: 'summaryLoyaltyCardFooter'
          Other 0x17457b540: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 528.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}, identifier: 'summaryLoyaltyCardFooter'
        }
        ↪︎Find: Element at index 0
          Output: {
            Other 0x17457c5c0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 178.0}, {375.0, 90.0}}, identifier: 'summaryLoyaltyCardFooter'
          }
          ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Button
            ↪︎Find: Elements matching predicate '"informationButton" IN identifiers'
```

Have you ever resolved this problem?

Comment: Are You sure that You have the same identifier set up for the button to its accessibility identifier property?

Comment: And another question, what is the output, when You use record and tap on that footer button. And have You enabled accessibility from the identity inspector for Your xibs / storyboards.

Comment: @GeorgiBoyadzhiev Yes, I'm sure I have this same accessibility identifiers. When I try to record action I only get the alert which I shown above. Yes, the accessibility form are enabled.

Comment: I had similar problem, but with a search field. Try when You are recording the test, to press the footer itself once before You press the button in it. Let me know how that goes and if You receive output for the footer tap.